# How to compare selected index of flatlist in next screen with integer number?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

As I am a beginner, Very confused about comparison in react native.
I have multiple different ImageArray like alphabets, fruits, birds etc. I want to load that according to selected index from flatlist like

```
if(selectedindex==1){
}
else if(selectedindex==2)
```

and so on.

How can I do? Please Help.

Comment: show you array here

Comment: const numberArray = [require('./Images/0.png'), require('./Images/1.png'), require('./Images/2.png'),
require('./Images/3.png'), require('./Images/4.png'), require('./Images/5.png'),
require('./Images/6.png'), require('./Images/7.png'), require('./Images/8.png'),
require('./Images/9.png')];

Answer (score 1):

The best way to create the object of the image

```
`const imageObject = { 0: require('./Images/0.png'), 1: require('./Images/1.png'), 2: require('./Images/2.png'),3: require('./Images/3.png'), 4:require('./Images/4.png'),5: require('./Images/5.png'),6: require('./Images/6.png')};`
```

Then use it using bracket notation like

```
  renderItem={(item, index) => <Image source={imageObject[index]} />}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your Array......
Inside the flatlist you have to modify the renderItem just like below

```
renderItem={({ item,index })
```

> Item is the value at the current index

When you want to target the index of the selected item then you have to use ***index*** for getting the position and for the data at that index you have to use ***item***

So, as per your code

```
if(index==1){
}
else if(index==2)
```

I hope this helps...Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You modify your code like this:

```
render(){
  const numberArray = [require('./Images/0.png'), require('./Images/1.png'), require('./Images/2.png'), require('./Images/3.png'), require('./Images/4.png'), require('./Images/5.png'), require('./Images/6.png'), require('./Images/7.png'), require('./Images/8.png'), require('./Images/9.png')];
  return(
    <FlatList
      data={numberArray}
      renderItem={(item, index) => {this.renderItem(item, index)}}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    />
  )
}

renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
  console.log("Element on" + index + "is" + item);
}
```